# How to modify page number

Tags: page-numbering

I want to add an integer to the page number, but `\thepage` seems to be a string and `\value{page}` doesn't show up on the page.

`\cfoot{\ifnum\value{page}<2\vspace{9pt}\value{page}+1\else\thepage+1\fi}`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! If you put it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
\cfoot{%
  \ifnum\value{page}<2\vspace{9pt}\the\numexpr\value{pa‌​ge}+1%
  \else\the\numex‌​pr\value{page}+1%
  \fi
}
```

The primitive `\numexpr` is used to perform calculations on numbers without changing counter or count register contents directly. In order to evaluate the expression as typesetting, the mighty `\the` as prefix is necessary.